# Java parameters errors, please assist

Tags: java

can't get this code to compile, I get an error that says:

`invalid method declaration;` `return type required public MineFinderFrame(int nc, int nr,int mod)`

please can anyone amend my code?

```
class MineFinderPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener
 {
int numCols;
int numRows;
int myModel;


 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    MineFinderFrame w = new MineFinderFrame(30,50,42);
    w.numRows = 50; // 50 rows
    w.numCols = 20; // 20 columns
    w.myModel = 42;
    w.setVisible(true);
}

public MineFinderFrame(int nc, int nr,int mod)
{
   numCols = nc;
   numRows = nr;
   myModel = mod;
   addMouseListener(this);

}
```

Comment: <del>You forgot the return type, it is void in this case. </del> Oh. I see this is a constructor... From the name, I thought it is just a badly named method...

Comment: MineFinderFrame this should be class

Comment: what return type would i put where?

Answer (score 4):

If you rename your class, you also have to rename the constructor in this class.

So I would start with this:

```
public MineFinderPanel(int nc, int nr,int mod)
{
   numCols = nc;
   numRows = nr;
   myModel = mod;
   addMouseListener(this);
}
```

And then, you would also have to change the first line in your main method to

```
MineFinderPanel w = new MineFinderPanel(30,50,42);
```

Comment: so this would go underneath the public MineFinderFrame?

Comment: No that would go instead of `public MineFinderFrame`.

Answer (score 1):

Your second function needs to declare a return type.

If your function is not supossed to return anything use **void**:

```
public void MineFinderFrame(int nc, int nr, int mod)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a class named `MindFinderFrame`, if that's the type you are instantiating. Did you mean to name MindFinderPanel as MindFinderFrame? (Or, other way around, perhaps you should be calling,

`MindFinderPanel m = new MindFinderPanel(...);`

Answer (score 1):

The method MineFinderFrame(int nc, int nr,int mod) does not say what type it returns.

Did you mean it to be the constructor? If so, is should be the same name as the class:

```
public MineFinderPanel(int nc, int nr,int mod) {
  numCols = nc;
  numRows = nr;
  myModel = mod;
  addMouseListener(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is `MineFinderFrame` supposed to be a constructor?

If yes, it **must** have the same name as the class (`MineFinderPanel`, not `MineFinderFrame`).
Otherwise, it is a normal method and it **must** have a return type.

Answer (score 0):

```
public MineFinderFrame (int nc, int nr,int mod)
```

is a constructor for a class called MineFinderFrame and you are trying to use it as a constructor of a class called MineFinderPanel.